# Async validation function for Swagger + Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, swagger

So, I'm using Node.js + Swagger + MongoDB.

I'm trying to validate that all requests come with a valid auth_token, which is a value stored on the user on mongo.
My problem is that the validators supported by Swagger need to return true or false, but since I have to check against Mongo to verify the auth token, the whole validation becomes asynchronous.

Here is the code in case you need it:

```
swagger.addValidator(
  function validate(req, path, httpMethod) {
      var apiKey = req.headers["auth_token"];
      if (!apiKey) {
        apiKey = url.parse(req.url,true).query["auth_token"]; 
      }

      models.user.validateAuthToken(apiKey, function(err, valid) {
        //Here is where I know if the auth token is valid and it checks against Mongo, so it's async
      });

    return [something]; //this is what the validation sequence is expecting this function to do: return true or false
 });
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, You might want to open a ticket with swagger to enable async validations.

Comment: Oh, I did,and submitted a pull requests.. let's hope they accept it. In case anybody needs it, I forked swagger and created a separate module with a fix for my needs, it's called: swagger-node-express-ext

Comment: @Deleteman: Is there any update for this issue? I saw your repository, but didn't found a pull request and your repo is outdated. Also, I found this discussion on google groups, also talking about some pull request which I can't find: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/UIgWkXYHBh0

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Swagger 1.2 or 2.0? If 2.0, you can use [swagger-tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools) to connect middleware for wiring up security handlers for requests based on Swagger documentation. It supports all swagger security mechanism defined in [Swagger Specification](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json#L1123).

Comment: This is an old question, I was probably using 1.2, but it's good that you put this updated information here, in case someone else comes in with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

And returning the result of the async function does not work?

```
swagger.addValidator(
  function validate(req, path, httpMethod) {
      var apiKey = req.headers[ 'auth_token' ];
      if (!apiKey) {
        apiKey = url.parse(req.url, true).query[ 'auth_token' ]; 
      }

      return models.user.validateAuthToken(apiKey, function(err, valid) {
        // check against mongo
        return validation;
      });    
 });
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but it doesn't sound like JS will wait for the validateAuthToken method to return in order to return from addValidator, it'll probably return null. Thanks though.